# How to calculate $ \int_0^s (s-r)^{-\alpha} e^{Ar} dr$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration

I have difficulty integration
$$ \int_0^s (s-r)^{-\alpha} e^{Ar} dr$$

Could anybody show me how to do this by hand?
The output i got from mathematica is confusing...
Appreciate for any helps!

Comment: Is $A$ dependent on $r$? What about $s$ or $\alpha$?

Comment: A is just a constant . All variables independent

Answer (score 1):

Change of variables $t = s-r$ makes this
$$ e^{As} \int_0^s t^{-\alpha} \exp(-At)\; dt $$
This can't be expressed in terms of elementary functions.  It can be written
using a hypergeometric function:
$$ {\frac {{s}^{-a+1}{{\rm e}^{As}}{\mbox{$_1$F$_1$}(-a+1;\,2-a;\,-As)}
}{1-a}}
$$
or in terms of the incomplete Gamma function:
$${{\rm e}^{As}}{A}^{a-1} \left( \Gamma \left( -a+1 \right) -\Gamma
 \left( -a+1,As \right)  \right) 
$$

Comment: exactly what I got from Mathematica. so, the integral still converges? By the way, the exponential can be estimated by some const.

Comment: The interval converges if $\alpha < 1$.

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is the *[fractional integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann%E2%80%93Liouville_integral)* of the exponential function.

See the book *[Fractional Integrals and Derivatives Theory and Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/2881248640)* (Section 5.1 and 9.3) for the result.

I don't think there is a trivial way to calculate the integral.